# How do I clean a cheap blow torch?

Tags: plumbing, tools, cleaning

I have one of those cheap Mapp gas + nozzle torches I'm using for sweat sodering and the tip clogged up today.  How do I go about cleaning it?

Comment: With most cheap tools, you dispose of it and buy a new one, as they are not made to be serviced. Did you drip solder into it?

Comment: No, definitely no solder in it, it actually worked 10 seconds before, turned it off and prepped the next joint and no hiss when I turned it on.  Can still had gas, I could feel it when I shook it.  And I tried a brand new can just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I have doubt it's even the tip clogging - could be a valve failure and have the described symptoms. I have never needed to clean the orifices on a propane torch, and I've been using them (the same ones, for the most part, other than having them walk off sometimes) for decades. Oxy-acetylene, yes - those can and do get sooted up. Propane/propylene-air - never.

Sometimes "cheap" is expensive, and "costly" is inexpensive.

Comment: I dropped one in the mud once and had to clean it, but otherwise I concur: never have had to clean during normal operation.